# Wpf gridview selected Item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have `ListView` with `GridView` inside view of `ListView` and `ListView` item source is specified. I dont seem to find how can. I get `SelectedItem` of `GridView` or `SelectedItem` changed.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,250,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding TestBinding}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedItem}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Test" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Test1}" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Test2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Test2}" Width="130" />                 
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: It seems you have a spelling mistake here: SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedItem}"  -> SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"

Comment: Hmm, I have very similar code to you and it works fine (binding to SelectedItem and SelectionChanged of the ListView picks up the internal GridView).  Can you give any more details of what's going wrong?

Comment: my selected changed event does not fire up.so its stuck there.. i guess i can remove that selectedItem property as it isnt working either

Comment: Could you please post the underlying ViewModel so that we can understand the binding?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code and it works fine:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    public class MyObj
    {
        public string Test1 { get; set; }
        public string Test2 { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TestBinding = new ObservableCollection<MyObj>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            TestBinding.Add(new MyObj() { Test1 = "sdasads", Test2 = "sdsasa" });
        }

        DataContext = this;
    }

    #region TestBinding

    private ObservableCollection<MyObj> _testBinding;

    public ObservableCollection<MyObj> TestBinding
    {
        get
        {
            return _testBinding;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_testBinding != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("TestBinding");
                _testBinding = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TestBinding");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region selectedItem

    private MyObj _selectedItem;

    public MyObj selectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("selectedItem");
                _selectedItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("selectedItem");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Used to notify the page that a data context property changed
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanging Members

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    // Used to notify the data context that a data context property is about to change
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Ran into a similar issue with updating, turned out I was missing this line in the constructor: DataContext = this;